# Upgrade App don´t show Admob house campaigns (Android)

Tags: admob

**In Android**

I have an app in the Play Store. In version 1.1.4 did not have house campaign but in version 1.2 i created a house campaign. The problem is that users upgrading from 1.1.4 to 1.2 banner ads are not visible, but if you uninstall 1.1.4 version and install version 1.2 the banners with house campign show so good. Why if you update the banners do not see?

PD: Only if you unninstall version 1.1.4 and install 1.2 banners Admob and house campign show correctly. If you upgrade, banners do not show...Why?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea about ads , But most probably it has something to do with existing databse(SQLite) or SharedPreference value , People having version 1.1.4 when are updating to 1.2 ,most probably there SharedPreference/database is remaining same are you using SharedPreference/database value somewhere to show those banner

Comment: Thanks so much, I will investigate that you tell me